# Starting weblogic server instance in jDeveloper

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper

I am having an issue starting a weblogic server instance in jdeveloper 11.1.1.6  The startWebLogic script starts, but then I receive the following error:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -jrockit
```

I tried some of the other solutions that people have posted for this error, but have had no success.  Some of the other suggestions involved JAVA_VM and the MEM_ARGS variables, but it didn't work for me.  I also dug up the tokenValues.properties file, and deleted the @JAVA_VM = -jrockit statement, and that didn't work either.

I am using weblogic server 11gR1.  Has anyone else had this problem in this environment?

Answer (score 0):

The `-jrockit` option is only for use with the jrockit JVM, I assume you are running with a standard JDK?

You might need to set `JAVA_VENDOR=Sun` at the top of your `startWebLogic` script to avoid it. Otherwise it sounds like it thinks your `JAVA_VENDOR=Oracle`, which means it will automatically tack on that `-jrockit` when your setDomainEnv script sources the `<weblogic home>/common/bin/commEnv` script.

The other option is to straight up modify `<weblogic home>/common/bin/commEnv` so it does whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  You were absolutely right, I was pointing to my jdk1.7 and that is not supported by jdeveloper ps6.  I needed to point to my jdk1.6.   I found that it was much easier to just re-install jdeveloper rather than attempting to find all of the spots in the script that pointed to jdk1.7