# Java vendor of particular jdk

Tags: java, weblogic, java-6

I am working with weblogic 11g server and now I want to change the jdk which is using by server for that I found some [hints](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1134583). for that I want to know the java vender of the jdk.

can any one know how to find java vendor for particular jdk version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jrockit -

```
JAVA_VENDOR=Oracle
```

If you are using the normal/standard jdk -

```
JAVA_VENDOR=Sun
```

You can set JAVA_VENDOR explicitly in your startWebLogic.sh or setDomainEnv.sh file if you are having problems. You can also set the JAVA_VENDOR on the `Server Start` tab in the admin console.

See these questions that more or less ask the same thing:

[WebLogic, choosing the JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089662/weblogic-choosing-the-jdk/21096718#21096718)

[Starting weblogic server instance in jDeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047374/starting-weblogic-server-instance-in-jdeveloper/22053229#22053229)